# Elements from file to structure

Tags: c, file, scanf, structure

Im trying to fscanf the content from a file to structure members an then printf them

Contents of the file is something like this:
d asd 12
**OR**
d asd 12 cash

The members of the structure are like this:

```
typedef struct customer
{
    char cname[20];
    char address[30];
    int units;
    char mode_of_payment[10];
} custo;
```

Here the display function takes in the name of the file and is supposed to output the contents baesd on some conditions

```
int display(char file_name[])
{
    printf("\n****************************************\n");
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;
    custo c;
    fp = fopen(file_name,"r");
    
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nFile name dose not exist\n");
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%s %s %d",c.cname,c.address,&c.units);
        printf("Customer details are as follows\n");
        ch=fgetc(fp);
        if(ch==EOF){
            printf("in first");
            printf("%s %s %d", c.cname, c.address, c.units);
        }
        else{
            printf("in second");
            fscanf(fp,"%s %s %d %s",c.cname,c.address,&c.units,c.mode_of_payment);
            printf("%s %s %d", c.cname, c.address, c.units, c.mode_of_payment);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

output is something like this:

---

Customer details are as follows
in firstp²a ☺ 0

expected output:
in first d asd 12
**OR**
in second d asd 12 cash

Comment: Check the return value from `fscanf` to be sure it read the data correctly.

Comment: `char ch;` --> `int ch;` in order to handle `EOF`

Comment: Aside: `display` is defined as returning an `int`, but returns nothing.

Comment: The second call to `fscanf` attempts to re-read the same data as the first. Unless you reposition the file, that data was already *consumed*. You probably meant to just read the *"mode of payment"*.

Comment: The `printf` call following the second `fscanf` has more variadic arguments than specifiers (the format string is missing a `%s` specifier).

Comment: please post something complete, compilable. And a a test file with a few lines so we can test the same thing you are seeing

Comment: @divyam – 
Now what does _the file_ contain - one of the given lines, or both?